# Using JavaScript in "button" self recognition on webpage

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a website in which I have placed specific buttons inside of articles and outside in the head/body/footer. What I plan to do is when a user clicks on the button the JavaScript code should find out if the button is located inside of an article or outside of it and send the information to my parent website using PHP's `$_GET` function. This is the code on the 'child' website..

```
<!-- Button code -->
<p id="test"></p>
<a id ="webs" href= "" onclick="jams(this);document.getElementById('test').frameBorder=0"; target="test"><button>Click me!</button> </a>
```

The JavaScript functions it calls.

```
<p id="demo"></p>


<script>
function jams(z) {
var origZ=z;
var found= false;
var sString;
while ( z.nodeName != "HTML"  && !found){
    var elements = z.getElementsByTagName('a');

    for(var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
        var input = elements[i] ;
        sString = input.getAttribute("href");

        found = sString.search(window.location.hostname) != -1;
     }
    z=z.parentElement;


    if ( z.nodeName != "HTML"  && z.nodeName !=                                                   "ARTICLE"){

     z=z.parentElement;
     var spString = (window.location.hostname);

         var link = "http://www.parentwebsite.com/one.php?id="+spString;
         origZ.href = link; 

    }     
}
var link = "http://www.parentwebsite.com/two.php?id="+sString;
origZ.href = link; 
}  
</script>
```

I have two pages on the parent website, *page* **one.php** receives the websites name (www.child.com) if the button is located outside of the article. 
 If the button is located within an article *page* **two.php** receives the articles URL.
Using PHP's `$_GET` Variable.

```
$success = $_GET["id"];
```

So when the user clicks the button on the webpage the button will call the *jams* script and it recognizes where the button is situated on the webpage and sends to either **one.php** the website-name OR **two.php** the articles URL.

The script works just fine when the button is situated within an article, 
the href =

```
http://www.parentwebsite.com/two.php?id=http://child-articles-url.com/
```

BUT it fails when it is outside of an article, the `href`

```
http://www.parentwebsite.com/two.php?id=http://www.parentwebsite.com/one.php?id=http://www.child.com/
```

What it needs to give is just:

```
http://www.parentwebsite.com/one.php?id=http://www.child.com/
```

P.S I have used chrome's debugger while working with this.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Seems you forgot to return from event handler when setting URL, thus the last assignment always gets executed. Just add `return` after your first  `origZ.href = link; ` appearance within the while loop.

Comment: It is very strange to have a button inside a link. Instead do `<a href="#" class="button" id="webs" onclick="jams(this);document.getElementById('test').frameBorder=0">Click me!</a>` and style the link

Comment: Also try `var spString = encodeURIComponent(window.location.href);`

Comment: @Boynux Adding `return` after the first `origZ.href = link;` The **one.php** would work fine, BUT it would present a new problem.. The functionality of the button inside of the article(when clicked) retrieves the same data as to a button outside of an article.

Comment: Then that means the logic to determine the button position is not correct. You may need to debug you JS logic to find out what's wrong with that. You're JS code posted above is not syntactically correct, so I can't give you more information.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to solve your problem

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Using JavaScript in “button” self recognition on webpage</title>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Your HTML CODE -->
<div class="aricle">
    <h2> Article Starts </h2>
        <a href="#" onclick="link(1);">This is inside Article</a>
    <h2> Article Ends </h2>
</div>
<br />
<a href="#" onclick="link(2);">This is inside Article</a>

<!-- Your JS CODE -->

<script type="text/javascript">
    function link(button) {

        if (button == 1) {
            //alert("button inside article");
            window.location.href='http://localhost/stackTest/one.php';
        } else if (button == 2) {
            //alert("button outside article");
            window.location.href='http://localhost/stackTest/two.php';
        }
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**one.php**

```
<h2>This is One</h2>
```

**two.php**

```
<h1>This is Two</h2>
```

Hope this helps you to identify the buttons.
and you can use the anchor (a) tags for displaying as a button instead using `<button>` tag inside `<a>..</a>` tag.
If you are using Bootstrap simply use "Button" Class for `<a>`.

Comment: Why not just `window.location.href='http://localhost/stackTest/two.php';` ? .assign is hardly used and slower

Comment: thanks. I tested both cases... assign is actually slower.